# How many times did they try and make a leviathan gunship?

Tags: farscape

It's mentioned in the Farscape series that there have been several failed attempts to make a Leviathan gunship, with the only successful one being Talyn.

I'm kind of curious as to how persistent the peacekeepers were in their breeding program. How many failed attempts were there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's never stated. It is alluded to several times, and there is one episode during season 2 involving a series of flashbacks that vaguely describes how the experiment was carried out aboard Moya. The only thing known for sure is that Talyn, was the only successful attempt. All previous efforts resulted in the death of both the mother and the offspring.